# не отображаются локальные изменения

Tags: android, android-studio

В Android Studio делаю изменения в файлах, затем - сommit,push. Все ок, отображается на GitHub. Но в local changes только - Default(no files). 
Как отобразить все комиты в локальных изменениях?

Comment: А что отображается на вкладочке Log?

Comment: история комитов. но это не то что надо. прежде в локальных изменениях мне удавалось наблюдать коммиты, с которых я мог извлечь код. а в лог просто записи.

Comment: Комиты с которых извлечь код? ЧТо бы это значило?

Comment: Сорян, я еще новичек в этом деле) Я тогда нажимал на запись прав. кн. - get . и текущий файл допустим java открывалсля исходя истории. 
И все же. как мне увидеть что то в local changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужна вкладка Log.
В этом случае справа отображается список файлов измененных в этом коммите.

При клике правой мышкой на файле есть варианты "Show Diff" и "Show Diff with Local".

Кроме того можно выделить какой либо файл или фрагмент кода и далее в меню:

VCS - Git  - Show history.

Похоже это то что вы ищите.

Comment: нет. допустим я пишу код в файле java. вчера я его дописал и закомитил. сегодня я этот же файл переделал и тоже закомитил. но вдруг мне захотелось запустить проект с версией файла которая была вчера. что для этого нужно?

Comment: На вкладке Log выбираете нужный вам коммит, и правой мышкой - `Checkout revision`. Когда надоело, на последний коммит и опять `Checkout revision`.

Comment: вот теперь большое спасибо)

Comment: @FunnyBunny если помог - отметьте ответ как правильный, там слева есть галочка.